# How would I get the actual value from a time complexity formula?

Tags: algorithms

So I've been learning about time complexity and have some understanding about how the formulas are determined from the code but I'm still lost on how exactly they would be used. As an example the AKS primality test has a time complexity of O(Log(n)^6) where N is the number of digits in the number. From what I understand since in coding Log base 2 is used if a number was 3 digits long the formula would be Log2(3)^6 = 15.85? Is that correct? Additionally does the value returned actually represent something like the number of runs the CPU does or is it meaningless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(log^6(n))$ that you mentioned is an asymptotic bound. When the size of the number, $n$ goes to $\infty$, the complexity gives the order of steps the algorithm will take to run, in terms of the asymptotic parameter(s). While time complexity is used to judge the efficiency of algorithms, it does not directly translate to finite values of the parameter directly, as you have done by taking $n = 3$. For such small values of $n$, it is meaningless to be using time complexity to judge CPU time or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ represents the value itself, not the number of digits.

> Additionally does the value returned actually represent something like the number of runs the CPU does or is it meaningless?

The value returned represents relative time of computation.

**Edit:** in theory the O function doesn't really return anything but it represents the time of computation. For example $O(n^3)$ will compute much longer than for example $O(x+2)$

Comment: "the algorithm takes less time than the twelfth power of the number of digits in n times a polylogarithmic (in the number of digits) factor" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Comment: It is because log(n) returns the number of digits minus one of a number. Example $\log_{10}557=2.\text{something}$

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is about growth rates, so you use it to scale already measured times.  It is also about asymptotic growth, so we don't necessarily expect it to hold in an implementation at small inputs.  Also distinguish between loose and tight bounds, e.g. $O(\log^{12}n)$ vs $O(\log^6n)$ for AKS where originally the former was proved but the latter was expected and is now a proven bound for a slightly modified AKS.

In the case of AKS, if we believe our implementation is correct and follows the $O(\log^6n)$ complexity we expect, then if we double the number of digits in the input we expect the run times to increase about $2^6 = 64$ times.  At small inputs the time is dominated by other factors, but once we're past those, good implementations will show something like that (probably more in the 70-100 range).

You could reverse this and measure the growth rate, but that gives you empirical data.  It's useful to verify expectations or give you a hypothesis of the algorithm's growth.